# How to remove the bracket and numbers inside the bracket?

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-science

[image]

I wrote this code but it is not giving me the correct answer. Kindly help me.

```
for text in hiv2['Number of deaths due to HIV/AIDS']:
   a=text.replace(' ','')
   b=a.split('[')
hiv2['Number of deaths due to HIV/AIDS']=b[0]
```

Comment: Can you please add how you want the expected answer to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.str.replace`

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]","")
```

Comment: can you explain me this part 'replace(r"\[.*\]" '

Comment: That is a regex matching the text inside brackets with brackets

Comment: And replacing with empty string